# Updating XAMPP changes UTF8 encoding behavior

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, xampp

I recently updated my XAMMP from version

1.7.4

- Apache 2.2.17
- MySQL 5.5.8 (Community Server)
- PHP 5.3.5 (VC6 X86 32bit) + PEAR

to version

1.8.2

- Apache 2.4.4
- MySQL 5.5.32 (Community Server)
- PHP 5.4.25 (VC9 X86 32bit thread safe) + PEAR

I have a function to "convert" UTF8 strings to ASCII and thus generating a valid filename. For example:
"èàòü" would become "eaou"

```
//converts all characters to ASCII equivalent (è->e)
function clearUTF($text){
    $f = array("&amp;amp", "&amp;", "&#039;", "&#7923;");
    $r = array("and", "and", "-", "y");
    $text = str_replace($f, $r, html_entity_decode($text));
    // replace non letter or digits by -
    $text = preg_replace('#[^\\pL\d]+#u', '-', utf8_encode($text));
    // trim
    $text = trim($text, '-');
    // transliterate
    if (function_exists('iconv')){
        $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    }
    // lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);

    // remove unwanted characters
    $text = preg_replace('#[^-\w]+#', '', $text);
    if (empty($text)){
        return 'n-a';
    }
    return $text;
}
```

This function works correctly on the old version of XAMMP but when I run it on the new one, I get "n-a" for any non-ascii string (for example "andrè"). I suppose this has something to do with the encoding or with the iconv function. Can anybody explain this weird behavior? Or another way to look at the question is:

*What has been changed between the two versions of XAMPP to change this behavior?* 
This can be useful for other people that go through the same update. I tried to compare the php.ini settings but couldn't find any difference there.

I should mention that the string passed as input comes from a database. But the collation of the tables is the same for both XAMPP version.

I also tried to remove the utf8_encode but this didn't solve the problem.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What if you leave `us-`, like this: `iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text)`? It was always work for me.

Comment: Be sure that you are consistent with all your encodings. PHP file, string to convert, database data, database connection, character set of file sent to the browser.

Also, remember to set your setlocale. Be sure that it's not POSIX or C, set it utf-8 or whatever you are using.

Do some intermediate var_dump to check how the information is moving on your script.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The question itself (I updated it right now to make it clearer) is not about encoding, though, it's more about what has been changed between the two different versions of XAMPP.